# Line Graphs in Anaconda

Tags: python, graph, package, anaconda, linegraph

I am writing a Python program to generate line graphs of cryptocurrency prices. 
 The goal is to be able to overlay multiple arbitrary pairs, i.e., BTC/USD + ETH/BTC, or BTC/USD + BCH/LTC + XRP/BTG, across the same horizontal timeline, similar to https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/ethereum/

The bells and whistles in the above example are not required.  It doesn't need click-to-zoom technology, the log-scale button, or fancy tool tips, if these features increase the implementation difficulty.  Separate colors for each line would be helpful.  This is the format of the data I have to work with:

https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histominute?fsym=BTC&tsym=USD&limit=60&aggregate=1&e=Coinbase

https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histominute?fsym=ETH&tsym=BCH&limit=30&aggregate=1&e=CCCAGG

Currently, I have Anaconda 3.6 on Visual Studio, which according to https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/py3.6_win-64.html should include multiple packages to plot this data without needing to manually install third party code through a command line.  However, when I try to import any of them (i.e., matplotlib, bokeh, seaborn), I receive a "ModuleNotFoundError" message, so I'm not sure if my Anaconda is functioning properly.  What is the easiest way to graph this data with Anaconda?

Comment: the python interpreter in vscode is probably not using your Anaconda installation. from vscode python shell type `import sys` and then `sys.version` and it should tell you the version of python you are using

Comment: This put me on the right track.  I solved the problem in Tool -> Python -> Python Environments by setting Anaconda to my default environment for new projects, then copying the code into a new VS project.

Comment: OK, great. I'll add this little bit to my answer as I have seen others ask about how to get anaconda in different editors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The python interpreter in VSCode is probably not using your Anaconda installation. In the VSCode python shell, type `import sys` and then `sys.version` and it should tell you the version of python you are using.

Here is some code to get you started with doing this in bokeh, a library that comes with Anaconda. Instead of using Visual Studio (or Visual Studio Code--I'm not sure which one you are referring to), I used `jupyter notebook`, and some of the import here are specific to that environment (to show the bokeh graph inline). You may want to format the date differently.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.io import output_notebook

import numpy as np
output_notebook()
import requests
import datetime
from math import pi
def format_date(utc_time):
    time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(utc_time))
    return time

url1 = "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histominute?fsym=BTC&tsym=USD&limit=60&aggregate=1&e=Coinbase"
url2 = "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histominute?fsym=ETH&tsym=BCH&limit=30&aggregate=1&e=CCCAGG"

r1 = requests.get(url1)
r2 = requests.get(url2)
r1_source = r1.json()["Data"]
r2_source = r2.json()["Data"]

r1_data = [i["close"] for i in r1_source]
r1_time = [format_date(i["time"]) for i in r1_source]
# r2_data = [i["close"] for i in r2_source]
# r2_time = [i["time"] for i in r2_source]

p = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=400)
p.line(r1_time,r1_data, line_width=2)

# p.line(r2_time, r2_data, line_width=2, line_color="red")

p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = pi/4
```

[image]